# Is the cosmic background radiation random and Kolmogorov complexity

Tags: cosmic-microwave-background, randomness

In the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0510102.pdf the idea arises that if there was a Creator of the Universe and wanted to send us a message, then the "right" place to do it, would probably be the the cosmic background radiation. One such message might simply be: "This message is not random.". How do we measure randomness of messages? Kolmogorov suggested the Kolmogorov complexity of a string, which is the shortest computer program to produce that string. If a string is random, then its Kolmogorov complexity would be high, or at least the size of the string. Now in reality this function is not computable, so one possible approximation is to use gzip, zip or any other compression algorithm to approximate the complexity.
My question is this:
Has this question been investigated?
(If so, what was the conclusion? :-) )
When would a gzipped version hint to a non-random message? (So does it have to be like half the message length or when would it count as non - random?)

Answer (score 2):

First, note that the distribution is to extremely good precision Planckian (as pointed out by @JohnDoty in the comments), which is consistent with random radiation.

This answer will focus on the temperature fluctuations, which are (as best as we can tell observationally) Gaussian.

Studies of the CMB have confirmed that the distribution of moments in the temperature fluctuations are consistent with a Gaussian distribution. For example, the $p$-value quantifying the probability that a Gaussian distribution would generate a $\chi^2$ as large or larger than the one observed in the temperature fluctuation map ($TT$) is around $75\%$, with the details depending on exactly how the map is created. See Table 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02552.

The link to Kolmogorov complexity isn't particularly deep. If you have a Gaussian random sequence, you can't write a computer program to generate that sequence, that is simpler than just recording all the data points. So establishing the Gaussianity is the key point to answer your question. An exception would be if the sequence was generated by some pseudo-random number generator, so the sequence wasn't truly random; but no one has a plausible model that generates CMB fluctuations with a pseudo-random number generator, and the CMB has passed all tests of Gaussianity that have been applied to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To your remark of deepness of Kolmogorov Complexity: Well how would you define the randomness of something? I am curious.

Comment: And the temperature fluctuations are a tiny perturbation of the precisely Planckian spectrum.

Comment: @JohnDoty Good point.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser You can use Kolmogorov Complexity to define randomness if you want to. It's just that from a physics point of view, KC doesn't really add anything in this context. It's just a way to quantify the physics idea that there is no model that predicts the specific realization of the $a_{\ell m}$ in the CMB.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me: Suppose you record the background radiation to some precision. Is it possible to compress this data with gzip and get half of the data size?

Comment: @mathoverflowUser Right, I understand. And the answer is no. If you generate a random sequence, there's no general algorithm you can use to compress it. There might be an algorithm that can compress a specific realization of the random process, but that's not what randomness is.

Comment: @Andrew: Ok, thanks for the link to the article.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser I'm not saying Kolmogorov Complexity is not a deep idea. I am just saying that its application in this context is trivial.